# Qmake and Make using separate folders for sources and headers

Tags: c++, qmake

I'm going mad on this stupid problem.

I've a tree like this:

```
src
|--- sources
        |--- one.cpp
        |--- two.cpp
        |--- sources.pro
|--- headers
        |--- one.h
        |--- two.hpp
        |--- headers.pro
|--- src.pro
```

I tried EVERYTHING to make it look in both the folders, but somehow I can't get it working. I don't know much about QMake, but I tought it was easy. And I was wrong.

So actually I ended up having the src.pro file in this way:

```
QT += dbus

CONFIG += warn_on
DEFINES = QT_FATAL_WARNINGS QT_NO_DEBUG_OUTPUT

devel {
  DEFINES -= QT_NO_DEBUG_OUTPUT
}

OBJECTS_DIR += build
MOC_DIR += build

TARGET = example

[...]

TEMPLATE = subdirs
SUBDIRS = sources \
          headers

[...]
```

And the sources.pro and headers.pro in this way:

**sources.pro**

```
SOURCES = one.cpp \
          two.cpp
```

**headers.pro**

```
HEADERS = one.h \
          two.hpp
```

And of course (not) the problem is that it still doesn't see the stuff all together.
I looked at the documentation too, but I swear I don't get it lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been awhile since I've had to use qmake (long live [CMake](http://cmake.org/)!), but can't you just set the `INCLUDEPATH` variable in your `.pro` file, i.e., do something like:

```
INCLUDEPATH += ./sources
INCLUDEPATH += ./headers
INCLUDEPATH += ../utils/include
# (etc, etc.)
```

Then just point the entry in your `SOURCES` var at the `sources` folder like so:

```
SOURCES = sources/one.cpp \
          sources/two.cpp
```

It's not clear to me why you're using `TEMPLATE = subdirs`.  It doesn't seem like it should be necessary in your case. Can't you just use `TEMPLATE = app` (or `TEMPLATE = lib`) and be done with it?  Something like this:

```
QT += dbus
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = example

INCLUDEPATH += ./sources

SOURCES += sources/one.cpp \
           sources/two.cpp
```

Comment: Thanks! I just fixed it by adding INCLUDEPATH += sources \ headers (which I also tried partially before posting the question) and adding the sources and headers path to all the files (sources/one.cpp headers/one.h) cause I tought it would have seen it as one unique folder :) Thanks a lot!