# Qmake using separate folders for sources and headers without modifying .pro

Tags: qmake

I'm want to compile meshlab(http://sourceforge.net/p/meshlab/code/HEAD/tree/) and put the generated file outside the source directory to keep the source clean. Is it possible to just specify a build directory as the way in cmake?

The answer in this post [Qmake and Make using separate folders for sources and headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4300330/qmake-and-make-using-separate-folders-for-sources-and-headers), requires to modify the .pro file and doesn't work in my case. Users may want to specify the build dir path as they like, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what are trying to do is a QMake Shadow Build. This question about [Manually Configuring Shadow Builds in QMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171896/manually-configuring-shadow-build-in-qmake) should help you.